# Exception in Docker Compose: Issues While Running My Docker Compose Configuration

Tags: elasticsearch, docker-compose, logstash, elk

I'm currently facing a perplexing issue with my Docker Compose setup involving Logstash. I've been following various tutorials to configure Logstash within an ELK (Elasticsearch, Logstash, Kibana) stack, but I keep encountering the following error when attempting to start the Logstash service:

> Failed to execute action {:action=>LogStash::PipelineAction::Create/pipeline_id:main, :exception=>"LogStash::ConfigurationError", :message=>"Expected one of [ \t\r\n], "#", "input", "filter", "output" at line 1, column 1 (byte 1)", :backtrace=>["/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/compiler.rb:32:in 'compile_imperative'", "org/logstash/execution/AbstractPipelineExt.java:239:in 'initialize'", "org/logstash/execution/AbstractPipelineExt.java:173:in 'initialize'", "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/java_pipeline.rb:48:in 'initialize'", "org/jruby/RubyClass.java:911:in 'new'", "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/pipeline_action/create.rb:50:in 'execute'", "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/agent.rb:386:in `block in converge_state'"]}

```
input {
  jdbc {
    jdbc_driver_library => "/usr/share/logstash/pipeline/mysql-connector-java-8.0.27.jar"
    jdbc_driver_class => "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
    jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test"
    jdbc_user => "test"
    jdbc_password => "test"
    statement => "SELECT * from tests"
  }
}

output {
   elasticsearch {
       hosts => ["http://elasticsearch:9200"]
       index => "sample"
  }
}
```

I've run docker compose up after making sure all necessary services are up and running.

Comment: This should be a format error for your config file. Are you sure your config file is totally same with what you shared in question?